# Mult method taking 2 integer parameters and find product

Tags: java, static-methods

I'm using Android aide.
My task is to use a mult method that takes 2 integer parameters and find the product of both.

```
public class Main
{
       Public static void (String [ ] args)
      {
      system.out.println (mult(10,100));
      system.out.println (mult (20,200));
      }
         {
          static int mult(int a, int b);
          return a * b;
          }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong or missing? Thanks.

Comment: I don't even think this compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Since, **I do not want to give the whole answer way** I just give you some hints

Some issues

**First**, your main method signature has wrong syntax.

**Second**, `system.out.print` has wrong syntax. hint you have to change just system part to have right
             syntax

**Third**, you have `{` in wrong places.

**hope these hints help you to figure this out**

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define a method. Do blindly copy it try to understand what happening here.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
      System.out.println(mult(10,100));
      System.out.println(mult (20,200));
    }

    public static int mult(int a, int b)
    {
       return a * b;
    }

}
```

A function is define as following

access_parameter optional_keyword return_type menthod_name(List_of_all_the_parameters) 
access_parameter can be private,public, protected or package private
optional_keyowrds can be static, abstract ...
return_type of the function can be primitive data type or a class if a function doesn't need to return any thing then void
menthod_name name of the method
List_of_all_the_parameters list of all the parameter that you want to pass.